# How to customise color of Local Variables in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, customization, jetbrains-ide, local-variables

Can we customise the color of Local variables in  IntelliJ ( or any other IDE by JetBrains)? I am able to customise the theme for colors of other types like string, numbers or data types, but Local variables always appear in a dull grey color.

I tried `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language Defaults -> Identifers -> Local Variables` and changed the color, but local variables in my code still appear in same dull grey color.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: 1) You should try changing that for the **actual language** used (it's Java as I understand) and not global Language Defaults. The actual language may override it .. or not have such style at all.

Comment: Yeah , its Java , but I don't think its about language defaults .Someone told me it has to something that I was not using a reputed style of coding , the local variables only change color once I use them somewehere in the code

Comment: 2) Use this trick to see what styles are used/can be applied: A) place caret on such variable in the editor; B) Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (should be `Ctrl+Shift+A` on Windows); C) type `jump to` there to locate `Jump to Colors and Fonts` entry there: https://i.imgur.com/TNGmZ7u.png ; D) You should now see the list of possible styles and jump right from there: https://i.imgur.com/qHT5AQm.png

Comment: *" the local variables only change color once I use them somewehere in the code"* That is correct: if variable is not used anywhere in the scope then it will have "unused variable" style applied. You will be able to see that with the above trick.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne your trick worked wonders

Answer (score 0):

Unused code is actually located under "General" -> "Errors and Warning".
Here is how mine looks changing to a yellow color:

[image: settings screenshot]